# Calculate SUM by date with week and month trick SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sum

What I am trying to achive is calculateing some statistic howewer I have dat in mail table by week< but i need to show statistic as for month/

for example in table i have this

```
 '20130226',    312.00
 '20130305',    833.00
```

Week which ends on 20130305  has 2 days in Feb and 5 in March. 
I am trying to achieve:

```
2013-02-28  550.000000
2013-03-31  2285.000000
```

I have this query:

```
    CREATE TABLE #Old
    (
    Weeks DATE,
    summ NUMERIC (12,6)    
)
        INSERT INTO #Old VALUES  ( '20130226',  312.00)
        INSERT INTO #Old VALUES  ( '20130305',  833.00)
        INSERT INTO #Old VALUES  ( '20130312',  225.00)
        INSERT INTO #Old VALUES  ( '20130319',  453.00)
        INSERT INTO #Old VALUES  ( '20130326',  774.00) 



 SELECT  
    EOMONTH ( Weeks  )
    , sum (summ)  as cumesum
    FROM  #Old
    GROUP BY  EOMONTH ( Weeks  )
```

I know its not right  because its not splitting that week in two months, but have no ideas how to achieve it.

Comment: You are aware that splitting aggregate data won't give you accurate results, right?  Do you still have the base data to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to allocate the weekly numbers by month.  One approach is to split the data between the current month and the previous month -- doing the allocation as arithmetic on the value.

The rest is just aggregation:

```
select EOMonth(weeks), sum(month_summ)
from ((select weeks, year(weeks) as yy, month(weeks) as mm,
              (case when day(weeks) >= 7 then summ
                    else summ * day(weeks) / 7.0
               end) as month_summ
       from #old o
      ) union all
      (select dateadd(month, -1, weeks) as weeks,
              year(dateadd(month, -1, weeks)) as yy,
              month(dateadd(month, -1, weeks)) as mm,
              summ * (1 - day(weeks) / 7.0)
       from #old o
       where day(weeks) < 7
      )
     )
group by EOMonth(weeks);
```

Comment: its T-SQL , and be honest its not quiet right  because i have to show  month as last day of the month like this `2013-03-31`

Comment: @Andrey . . . That is a very small change to the query, which I just made.

Comment: Has to re wright it  but  thanks probably your example work for MySQl but this structure didn't work for MSSQL? i did it trough CTE

Comment: @Andrey . . . I think I fixed the typos, but SQL Fiddle is really slow and acting up (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/250c6/3).